# How do I use android fragment java class?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I set up a fragment which looks like this:

[image]

The EditText("5") has the id et_input. Now I want to interact with my EditText but it doesn't work.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

/**
 * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
 * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
 * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
 * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
 * may be best to switch to a
 * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
 */
private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

/**
 * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
 */
private ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

    getSupportActionBar().hide();
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
     * number.
     */
    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        switch (getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER) - 1) {
            case 1:
                return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_roman_numbers, container, false);
            case 2:
                return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_binary_numbers, container, false);
            default:
                return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        if(position == 0) {
            return main.newInstance();
        } else if(position == 1) {
            return roman_numbers.newInstance();
        } else if(position == 2) {
            return binary_numbers.newInstance();
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("There is no fragment for position [" + position + "]");
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return getString(R.string.fragment_home);
            case 1:
                return getString(R.string.fragment_roman_numbers);
            case 2:
                return getString(R.string.fragment_binary_numbers);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

**binary_numbers.java**

```
public class binary_numbers extends Fragment {

public binary_numbers() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

public static binary_numbers newInstance() {
    binary_numbers fragment = new binary_numbers();
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_binary_numbers, container, false);
    EditText et_input = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.et_input);
    et_input.setText("TEST");

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return view;
}
}
```

*roman_numbers.java and main.java look exactly the same except for binary_numbers being replaced with their names.*

**fragement_binary_numbers.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.ngtnttnmnt.xtool.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">


<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/et_input"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:hint="@string/input_hint"
    android:gravity="center" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=""
    android:id="@+id/tv_output"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textSize="40dp"
    android:gravity="center" />
```

*fragement_roman_numbers.xml looks exactly the same and fragement_main.xml has two TextView's*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_binary_numbers, container, false);
    EditText et_input = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.et_input);
    et_input.setText("TEST");

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return view;
}
```

**EDIT:**

As I said, you're showing a different fragment. In reality, you are showing the `PlaceholderFragment` created within your `SectionsPagerAdapter`, which just selects the `binary_number` layout when it's inflated, but you're not actually showing a `binary_numbers` fragment.

Your code should be the following:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
private ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

    getSupportActionBar().hide();
}

public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        if(position == 0) {
            return home.newInstance();
        } else if(position == 1) {
            return roman_numbers.newInstance();
        } else if(position == 2) {
            return binary_numbers.newInstance();
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("There is no fragment for position [" + position + "]");
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return getString(R.string.fragment_home);
            case 1:
                return getString(R.string.fragment_roman_numbers);
            case 2:
                return getString(R.string.fragment_binary_numbers);
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("There is no fragment for position [" + position + "]");
    }
}
}
```

Please note the complete removal of the `PlaceholderFragment` class, because you won't need it, ever.

**EDIT:** also add

```
public class home extends Fragment {
    public static home newInstance() {
        return new home();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle saveInstanceState) {
         return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

Also modify your `binary_numbers` class like so

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.text.InputFilter;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.ngtnttnmnt.xtool.InputFilterMinMax;
import com.ngtnttnmnt.xtool.R;

public class binary_numbers extends Fragment {

public binary_numbers() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

public static binary_numbers newInstance() {
    binary_numbers fragment = new binary_numbers();
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_binary_numbers, container, false);
    EditText et_input = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.et_input);
    et_input.setText("TEST");

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return view;
}
}
```

Comment: It is still not showing "TEST", when I go to the fragment, in the EditText.

Comment: Then what you see is not actually your fragment.

Comment: I have an xml file where I set up my editText. By creating that Android Studio also created the fragments class.. And since it shows the stuff I put into my xml when I go to the fragment I guess I see the right one.

Comment: Nope, I'm pretty sure you're modifying another fragment's code that you are not showing, because the fragment where you're "deciding which fragment to show" is actually just returning views, not fragments.

Comment: okay I don't get that. That is my problem. could you explain how I can interact with my EditText then or how it works :)?

Comment: What are your two fragment classes? `public class ____?`

Comment: the name of the fragement xml without the fragement_ infront. So if my fragement was called test and the xml was fragement_test.xml the class would be public class test extends Fragement

Comment: And what's the **other** fragment? You have `Fragment0`, `Fragment1`, `Fragment2`, and `BinaryNumbers`?

Comment: no. That was just for the example. I have the fragment_main, fragment_roman_numbers and fragment_binary_numbers. I edited the reference in my question.

Comment: Not enough data to answer this question. You did not specify any of your fragment transactions, and you did not specify your fragments.

Comment: Right. There's also `fragment_main`, and your Activity code is still unknown.

Comment: I said that there is the fragment_main and what do you mean by my activity code? I don't have any at the moment. I just did the design. I want to start now and that is where my problem occured.

Comment: ....in order to answer this question, the code for `MainActivity` is required. It would also be nice to know the names of the fragments that you're actually showing the `onCreateView`s of in the post.

Comment: I posted my mainactivity code even though th rest I added is just the standard code..

Comment: This code `mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);` what class is it in?

Comment: it is in the binary_numbers class

Comment: I see. In that case, apparently the SectionsPagerAdapter code is also here, so I can finally answer the question. Stay tuned

Comment: Yeah I noticed. Also I've answered the question now

Comment: Since the one you called "home" is the main fragment and works in the MainActivity.java what should I return there?

Comment: Your `public class home extends Fragment` class. But if you don't have such a thing, then just omit it, return `2` in `getCount()`, and modify the indexes for their titles accordingly.

Comment: it is not called home. The string value is called home. It is the fragement_main which is created by Android Studio

Comment: What exception? This should work perfectly fine. Although considering `fragment_main` was the placeholder fragment, I'll just have to modify again... (modified the sections pager adapter)

Comment: There IS actually 3 pages. I don't know if you ever worked with the tabbed fragement in Android Studio, but it automatically generates a fragement_main which is the first page.

Comment: it says `java.lang.RuntimeException: com.ngtnttnmnt.xtool.MainActivity@590c7a must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener` so your **`MainActivity` should implement `OnFragmentInteractionListener`**

Comment: I just created it with Android Studio rather than typing it ^^

Comment: So now it says I need OnFragmentInteractionListener and that it cannot change tag of fragment PlaceholderFragment

Comment: ....**sigh** changed binary_numbers fragment accordingly, I removed `OnFragmentInteractionListener` because you won't need it yet

Comment: I don't see anything changed there except that you removed the params..

Comment: And all the other crap. Just replace your `binary_numbers` fragment with it entirely.

Comment: Nice! I don't get errors anymore. But still it doesn't work and I think that it is not even called, because I pasted that EditText thing into the two other fragements too and there is no EditText and it didn't throw any exception. Also in binary numbers it didn't change it :/

Comment: In that case, I'll have to ask you to update your initial post and update the `MainActivity` class, the `binary_numbers` class, add the `roman_numbers` and `home` fragment. Also the `binary_numbers` layout XML. Just edit out the initial setup, because that won't be needed anymore (SO will remember it anyways)

Comment: Did it. Put everything in.

Comment: Two things, **1.)** remove the `PlaceholderFragment` class from your `MainActivity`, and **2.)** try to `setText("123")` or something like that - String parameter, but only containing numbers (your input type is `number`, so EditText will only accept numeric characters) instead of `setText("TEST")`

Comment: You are a god for keeping up that long! Thank you so much. I finally get what the problem was AND it is solved. Removing the PlaceholderFragement did it because it was not even calling the fragement classes. Thumbs up for that one.

Comment: Glad we got it working - the auto-generated fragment code of Android Studio is an abysmal mess :P

Answer (score -1):

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
private PlaceholderFragment mPlaceholderFragment;
public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    if(mPlaceholderFragment == null){
      mPlaceholderFragment = PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
    }
    return mPlaceholderFragment;
}
```

It should be like this